# How to invoke FFMPEG automatically from browser using shell script

Tags: shell

We are working on uploading videos to media server and convert them to mp4 format using ffmpeg.We are able to write a "php code" that does conversion when it is executed from a terminal using "php convert.php".But we want to make the conversion automatic.So we are trying to use "system(myscript.sh)" command where "myscript.sh" contains the ffmpeg conversion command.But it is not working.If we try to store "ls-l" in "myscript.sh" and run it in browser it's working fine. Only ffmpeg is not working.Guys any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not you set your php script in cronjobs.

Comment: can u tell me how to use cronjobs to convert files in background?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: * * * * * <path of php executable path> <path of php script file>

Comment: i want this job to be finished as soon as i click a "button" and return "resulting converted video" along with its "thumbnails" that is the result of the cron job.
All this process should happen in seconds. No waiting should be involved. how do i do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe the process? Like uploading , transcoding ( save converted file or transcoded  and send the  trans coded video on fly) . How you want to sink the process in terms of user experience